# client and server UDP in one code - sendto invalid argument

Tags: c, udp, client

I would like write chat between two users. Client and server should be in one file and the program runs each user on his computer using the IP of the other user.

I mean

User1

> ./program 1.2.3.4

User2

> ./program 4.3.2.1

But when I turn on the programme, I get a message 'invalid arrgument' the problem is in the sendto function, but I do not know why

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>

int exit_with_perror(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int sockfd, s;
u_short my_port;
struct addrinfo hints, hints_lok;
struct addrinfo *server_info, *client_info, *p;
struct sockaddr *server_addr;

void handler(int sig) 
{
    freeaddrinfo(server_info);
    freeaddrinfo(client_info);
    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    
    my_port = 5000 + (getpid()%10000);
    char str[10];
    sprintf(str,"%d", my_port); =
  
    
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
   
    
    s = getaddrinfo(argv[1], str, &hints, &server_info); 
    
    if(s != 0)
    {
        exit_with_perror("getaddrinfo");
    }
    
    
    for(p = server_info; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if((server_addr = p->ai_addr)!= NULL)
        {
        break;
        }
    }
    
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        printf("address error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
        
    freeaddrinfo(client_info);
   
    memset(&hints_lok, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints_lok.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints_lok.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints_lok.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; 
    
    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, str, &hints_lok, &client_info); 
     
     if(s != 0)
     {
         exit_with_perror("getaddrinfo");
     }
    
    for(p = client_info; p!= NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
        {
            perror("socket: ");
            continue;
        }
        
        if(bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
          
            perror("bind: ");
            continue;
        }
        
        break;
    }
    
    if(p == NULL)
    {
       exit(1);
        
    }
    freeaddrinfo(client_info);
    char buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    
    
    if(inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((const struct sockaddr_in *)server_addr)->sin_addr), buf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN) == NULL)
    {
        perror("inet_ntop");
        exit(1);
        
    }
     
    int pid;
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler);
    char msg[120];
    
  if((pid = fork())==0)
  {
      
      while(1)
      {
          if(recvfrom(sockfd, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, NULL, NULL) == -1)
          {
          perror("recvfrom: ");
          exit(1);
          }
          
          printf("%s\n", msg);
      }
      
     
      
  }else if(pid == -1)
  {
      perror("fork: ");
      exit(1);
  }else
  {
      while(1)
      {
          fgets(msg, 120, stdin); 
          if(sendto(sockfd, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
          {
              perror("sendto: ");
              exit(1);
          }
      }
  }
    
    
      return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Where did you set `server_addr` port and domain ?

Comment: hints_lok.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints_lok.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints_lok.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; 
    
    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, str, &hints_lok, &client_info);    the name is misleading, because I wanted to make sure that what I get from the user is the address of the server I send to, and then I create a local server in the code

Comment: You aren't checking return values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather common typo pattern in C code.

```
 if(sendto(sockfd, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
```

`sizeof(server_addr)` is the size of the pointer.  You need `sizeof(*server_addr)` to pass the size of the underlying `struct sockaddr`.

The kernel is detecting that 8 (size of pointer) is less than 16 (size of sockaddr), and returning `Invalid Argument`.